# Android: SwipeListView-not responds to swipe but working on click [Logcat shows couldn't open '/dev/touch' (no such file or directory)]

Tags: android, swipe

So the SwipeListView is working,but it does not respond to swipe but working on click.
my Xmls are as follows :

```
 <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff" >

<com.fortysevendeg.android.swipelistview.SwipeListView
    xmlns:swipe="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/lstRequests"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:listSelector="#00000000"
    swipe:swipeBackView="@+id/back"
    swipe:swipeCloseAllItemsWhenMoveList="true"
    swipe:swipeDrawableChecked="@drawable/choice_selected"
    swipe:swipeDrawableUnchecked="@drawable/choice_unselected"
    swipe:swipeFrontView="@+id/front"
    swipe:swipeMode="left" >
</com.fortysevendeg.android.swipelistview.SwipeListView
```

package_row.xml:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/back"             <===
    style="@style/ListBackContent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="110dp"   
    android:tag="back" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/backshowportion"
    style="@style/ListBackContent"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="110dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
    android:gravity="right|center" >

    <TextView
         ..... />

    <TextView
         ..... />

    <TextView 
         ...../>

</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/front"            <===
    style="@style/ListFrontContent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="110dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:tag="front" >

    <TextView
         ..... />

    <TextView
         ..... />

    <TextView
         ..... />

    <TextView
         ..... />


</RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

and Class as follows:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    swipeListView=(SwipeListView)findViewById(R.id.lstRequests);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) 
    {
        swipeListView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
    }
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) 
    {
        swipeListView.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new AbsListView.MultiChoiceModeListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode mode, int position,long id, boolean checked)
            {
                mode.setTitle("Selected (" + swipeListView.getCountSelected() + ")");                  
            }
            @Override
            public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) 
            {
                swipeListView.unselectedChoiceStates();
            }
            @Override
            public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode,MenuItem item) 
            {
                return false;
            }
            @Override
            public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) 
            {
                return false;
            }
            @Override
            public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu)
            {
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
}
public void onStart()
{
    super.onStart();        
    listner(); 
}
private void listner()
{
     swipeListView.setSwipeListViewListener(new BaseSwipeListViewListener() 
     {          
            @Override
            public void onStartOpen(int position, int action, boolean right)
            {
                 Log.d("swipe", String.format("onStartOpen %d - action %d", position, action));
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartClose(int position, boolean right)
            {
                Log.d("swipe", String.format("onStartClose %d", position));                 
            }   

            @Override
            public void onOpened(int position, boolean toRight)
            {   

            }   

            @Override
            public void onMove(int position, float x)
            {

            }   

            @Override
            public void onListChanged()
            {

            }

            @Override
            public void onLastListItem()
            {   

            }   

            @Override
            public void onFirstListItem()
            {   

            }   

            @Override
            public void onDismiss(int[] reverseSortedPositions) 
            {

            }

            @Override           
            public void onClosed(int position, boolean fromRight) 
            {   

            }   

            @Override
            public void onClickFrontView(int position)
            {
                Log.d("swipe", String.format("onClickFrontView %d", position));
                swipeListView.openAnimate(position);
            }   

            @Override
            public void onClickBackView(int position)
            {
                Log.d("swipe", String.format("onClickBackView %d", position));
                swipeListView.closeAnimate(position);
            }

            @Override
            public void onChoiceStarted() 
            {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChoiceEnded() 
            {   

            }   

            @Override
            public void onChoiceChanged(int arg0, boolean arg1) 
            {

            }   

            @Override
            public int onChangeSwipeMode(int arg0)
            {
                return 0;
            }
        });
```

Whenever swipes or click at SwipeListView, logCat shows as follows:

VelocityTracker........couldn't open '/dev/touch' (no such file or directory)

VelocityTracker........tpd read x fail: Bad file number

VelocityTracker........tpd read y fail: Bad file number

Help me please.Thanks in advance.